# How to show implication for equivalent equations?

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability

What does it mean for one event  to cause another event  — for example, smoking () to cause cancer ()? There is a long history in philosophy, statistics, and the sciences of trying to clearly analyze the concept of a cause. One tradition says that causes raise the probability of their effects; we may write this symbolically is
(|)>().(1)

Another way to formulate a probabilistic theory of causation is to say that
(|)>(|^).(2)

I know that equation (1) implies that (|)>().

Show that equation (1) implies equation (2)

Comment: Perhaps you you subtract both sides of $P(C \mid E)>P(C)$ form $1$ to give $P(C^C \mid E)<P(C^C)$ and then reverse the process.

Comment: Incidentally, I am interested in how you wrote your inequalities: you seem to have used something between images and sloping characters.  Is it some strange form of Unicode?

Comment: @Henry I am reasonably sure that they are just italicized serif characters in Unicode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the law of total probability, we can relate $P(E)$ to $P(E\mid C)$ and $P(E\mid C^c)$

$$P(E) = P(E\mid C)P(C) + P(E\mid C^c)(1-P(C)) = P(C)[P(E\mid C) - P(E\mid C^c)] + P(E\mid C^c) $$

Using our assumption $P(E\mid C) > P(E)$ we get:

$$P(C)[P(E\mid C) - P(E\mid C^c)] + P(E\mid C^c) = P(E) < P(E\mid C)$$

Collecting conditional probabilities on either side of the inequality we get

$$  P(E\mid C^c)- P(C)P(E\mid C^c)  < P(E\mid C) - P(C)P(E\mid C) $$

Finally, we factor out $1-P(C)$ on both sides:

$$ (1-P(C))P(E\mid C^c) < (1-P(C))P(E\mid C)$$

Assuming $P(C) < 1$ ($P(C)=1$ would make it omnipresent and not a typical "cause"), we can divide by the strictly positive value $1-P(C)$ to get our implication:

$$P(C) < 1 \text{ and } (1-P(C))P(E\mid C^c) < (1-P(C))P(E\mid C) \implies P(E\mid C^c) < P(E\mid C)\;\; \square$$